# Why keras model.fit_generator() showing error like Failed to get convolution algorithm?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

`tensorflow version` -> 2.0.0

`keras version` --> 2.2.4

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    featurewise_center=False,  # set input mean to 0 over the dataset
    samplewise_center=False,  # set each sample mean to 0
    featurewise_std_normalization=False,  # divide inputs by std of the dataset
    samplewise_std_normalization=False,  # divide each input by its std
    zca_whitening=False,  # apply ZCA whitening
    rotation_range=10,  # randomly rotate images in the range (degrees, 0 to 180)
    zoom_range = 0.1, # Randomly zoom image 
    width_shift_range=0.1,  # randomly shift images horizontally (fraction of total width)
    height_shift_range=0.1,  # randomly shift images vertically (fraction of total height)
    horizontal_flip=False,  # randomly flip images
    vertical_flip=False)  # randomly flip images

datagen.fit(X_train)


history = model.fit_generator(datagen.flow(X_train,Y_train,batch_size=batch_size,),
                         epochs=epochs,validation_data=(X_val,Y_val),
                         verbose=2,steps_per_epoch=X_train.shape[0] // batch_size,
                         callbacks=[learning_rate_reduction])
```

**Error:**

> UnknownError: Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably
>   because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning
>   log message was printed above. [Op:Conv2D]

Comment: Are you running on a GPU? If yes, what version cuda, cudnn do you have?

Comment: yes i am running on GPU.but i don't know which Cuda and cudnn version to install?

Comment: You need CUDA version 10.0 and cuDNN version 7.4.1, as well as the NVIDIA GPU drivers. You can see the instructions [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu).

Comment: thank you already installed it and worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

[try this worked for me](https://towardsdatascience.com/installing-tensorflow-with-cuda-cudnn-and-gpu-support-on-windows-10-60693e46e781)

cuda version --> 10.0
cudnn version --> 7.6.4

tensorflow gpu version --> 2.0.0
keras gpu version --> '2.2.4'